# Photoshop changes tablet screen area

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tablet, bamboo

Usually my Wacom Bamboo tablets screen area (Area which cursor can go using tablet) is as set - One (1280x1024) monitor. However, when I run any Adobe Product, such as PhotoShop or Illustrator (CS5 or CS4), and it is the active window, my screen area reduces to around 400x400, effectively making itself absolutely useless.
If another program is the active window, it works fine.

Running Windows 7 32-bit, with up-to-date tablet drivers.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same damn problem this week -- and I even tried restoring my computer system, but in vain.
Finally, today, I tried this: I completely uninstalled the tablet driver from my PC (via Control Panel) and installed it again.

The problem seems to be solved -- well, at least for now.